# JavaScript Performance: Loop and indexOf with large Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops, indexof

I currently have a problem with the performance of a JavaScript operation.

I want to clean up an object array (aEmployees) for those objects whose ID is already in the array `aInvited` or which are not in the `aInvitationAllowed` array:

```
var iLength = aEmployees.length - 1;
for (var i = iLength; i >= 0; --i) {
   if (aInvited.indexOf(aEmployees[i].id) !== -1 || aInvitationAllowed.indexOf(aEmployees[i].id) === -1) {
      aEmployees.splice(i, 1);
   }
}
```

You can imagine that I have Employee objects (aEmployees). I also have a list of Employee IDs that have already been invited to an event (aInvited) and a list of Employee IDs that are allowed to be invited to the event (aInvitationAllowed). I want to have all Employees as a result that I can still invite to the event.

The problem is the line with the `indexOf` queries. I have to assume that the arrays have very many entries (~ 100,000 entries). Then it may be that taking the loop takes a while.

So my question to you: How can I make the loop faster? Are there faster alternatives for `indexOf`?

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: Not sure it it can be help but take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Ideally, you don't let an array get anywhere near that large!

Comment: Loop the invited array once and create an array with `invited[employee.id] = true`. Then you can check for `if (invited[id]===true) {}`

Comment: @AustinTFrench Sure... However, in this case I have currently no other option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using a `Set` to compare instead. `Set.has` is an `O(1)` operation, whereas `indexOf` is an `O(n)` operation, reducing the computational complexity overall to `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`:

```
const aInvitedSet = new Set(aInvited);
const aAllowedSet = new Set(aAllowed);

const iLength = aEmployees.length - 1;
for (let i = iLength; i >= 0; --i) {
  const { id } = aEmployees[i];
  if (aInvitedSet.has(id) || !aAllowedSet.has(id)) {
    aEmployees.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Also, `splice` is slow-ish. Unless you *have* to mutate the exising array, you might consider `.push`ing to a new array instead (which looks to be [faster](https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-filter) than `Array.prototype.filter`):

```
const aInvitedSet = new Set(aInvited);
const aAllowedSet = new Set(aAllowed);
const newArr = [];

const iLength = aEmployees.length;
for (let i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {
  const employee = aEmployees[i];
  const { id } = employee;
  if (!aInvitedSet.has(id) && aAllowedSet.has(id)) {
    newArr.push(employee);
  }
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance Appreciate that! I'll give it a try and test.

Comment: This answer worked perfect for me! I had a huge improvement for the execution time of my JS code.

Comment: I found out that Set is not supported in IE11. Do you know some alternative for that case?

Comment: Assuming the `id`s are all one type, string or number, you can use object property lookup instead, eg `if (id in aInvitedObj && !(id in aAllowedObj))`